# This java program produce unwanted results

Tags: java, input

I wrote a program that read input and then print it out.

```
public class inverse {


public static void main (String arg[]) throws IOException {
    int input1 = System.in.read();
    System.out.println(input1);
    String temp=  Integer.toString(input1);
    System.out.println(temp);
    int[] numtoarray =new int[temp.length()];
    System.out.println(temp.length());
    for (int i=0 ;i<temp.length(); i++)
    {numtoarray[i]= temp.charAt(i);
    System.out.println(numtoarray[i]+"*");
    }

}}
```

but here when I write 123456 it print 49. but it should print 123456. what cause this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`123456` is an integer, but `System.in.read()` reads the next byte as input so it will not read the integer as expected. Use the `Scanner#nextInt()` method to read an integer:

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
int input1 = input.nextInt();
```

Your `numtoarray` array will also print the bytes, not the individual characters of the integer parsed as a string. To print the characters, change the type to a `char[]`:

```
char[] numtoarray = new char[temp.length()];
System.out.println(temp.length());
for (int i = 0; i < temp.length(); i++) {
    numtoarray[i] = temp.charAt(i);
    System.out.println(numtoarray[i] + "*");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`read()` doesn't read a number, it reads one byte and returns its value as an int. If you enter a digit, you get back 48 + that digit because the digits 0 through 9 have the values 48 through 57 in the ASCII encoding.

You can use Scanner instead

Here is the code

```
public static void main (String[] args) {

Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
int input1 = in.nextInt();
System.out.println(input1);
String temp=  Integer.toString(input1);
System.out.println(temp);
char[] numtoarray =new char[temp.length()];
System.out.println(temp.length());
for (int i=0 ;i<temp.length(); i++){
  numtoarray[i]= temp.charAt(i);
  System.out.println(numtoarray[i]+"*");
 }
}
```

<kbd>[**DEMO**](http://ideone.com/bspFU7)</kbd>

Comment: Java `char` is a Unicode/UTF-16 code unit, not an ASCII codepoint.

Comment: Working backwards, `new Scanner(System.in)` uses the "system default encoding" so the use must type (or pipe) the digits using that encoding and Scanner will convert it to UTF-16. The system default encoding is probably Windows-1252 or the like or UTF-8, almost certainly not ASCII.

Comment: when did I say char is not UTF-16

Comment: Your reference to "the ASCII encoding" is confusing.